# Python GUI custom buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, custom-controls, clickable

I am looking to make a GUI in python but currently do not have much experience.  The GUI must have a few key features, namely a slider bar to control audio, and a few basic menu buttons. I realize essentially all GUI development tools could handle these simple features, but I am also interested in some custom content as well. The basic look of the GUI I am looking to create is shown here:

[image]

In the image, the slider volume bar, "button1," "button2," the colored circles, and any slice of the circle (one highlighted section is shown) needs to be clickable and interactive. Moreover, the small colored circles must be able to dynamically revolve around the edge of the circle and remain clickable at all times. I have not used any GUI development tools yet, but have looked into pyGTK, pyQT, wxWidgets, and Kivy. Can anyone who has used these tools recommend which would be best suited? As far as shapes of buttons, am I restricted?

Comment: more important than the GUI - is the program, you should first have a working program that works independently of the GUI, and then the question becomes more interesting - what exactly is the program doing? this will determine which method of GUI you use, if its a music player then its not so important, if it needs to be a webpage, or part of a game, or only a single screen in the rest of the app, are you going to pop-up windows? are you going to have menus? minimize to tray? what else is this program doing?

Comment: 1): The purpose of the GUI is to give a visual representation of the locations (direction only) of human speakers within a room relative to a microphone device.  Assuming the appropriate information can be passed from this device as an input, I would like to represent these speakers by the colored circles shown in the image.  Clicking on a particular circle will ideally open a small popup window giving the option to mute this identified direction (and making the circle red), or to track this speaker (making the circle green)....

Comment: 2.) The segments of the circle (highlighted blue) would be clickable to specify a fixed listening direction. The volume slider would adjust a live stream of audio data (by passing the desired volume level back to the external device).  For this application it is safe to assume that the locations of speakers can be identified by an outside device which must pass information to the GUI.  I must also be able to pass information back to the microphone device....

Comment: 3.): This is not intended to be a webpage, isn't designed as a game but probably has some similar features, and is the main screen of the app with the exception of some pop-up menus.  The functionality is most important, but if I can strive for the look of the image I provided, I will definitely do so. Thanks again!

Comment: first of all, this sounds very interesting. as i mentioned earlier, you should have all these elements working before you start implementing the GUI. it seems you want to do something which is a bit outside the simple script scope that is python, i suggest you might want to use a langauge, or platform (because some do exist, like pydev) better suited for large scale applications like that, one that supports the gui as well, with real-time debugging. but if you are set in your ways than i think the answer below already has led you towards a few options.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pyopengl, pygame , pygtk .

I have one example how to show this images if you want take a look at :

http://free-tutorials.org **software free** section is **decor.tgz** example.

In my opinion you can use **pyOpenGL** is very portable to another language like C,C++ and also you can make it to Linux , Windows , Android.